# Numerical Python - how do I make this a ufunc?

Tags: python, numpy

new to NumPy and may not be searching properly, so I'll take the lumps if this is a common question...

I'm working on a problem where I need to calculate log(n!) for relatively large numbers - ie. to large to calculate the factorial first, so I've written the following function:

```
def log_fact(n):
    x = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        x += log(i)
    return x
```

Now the problem is that I want to use this as part of the function passed to curve_fit:

```
def logfactfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a*log_fact(x) + b*x + c

from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

curve_fit(logfactfunc, x, y)
```

However, this produces the following error:

```
File "./fit2.py", line 16, in log_fact
    for i in range(1,n+1):
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

A little searching suggested numpy.frompyfunc() to convert this to a ufunc

```
curve_fit(np.frompyfunc(logfactfunc, 1, 1), data[k].step, data[k].sieve)

TypeError: <ufunc 'logfactfunc (vectorized)'> is not a Python function
```

Tried this as well:

```
def logfactfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a*np.frompyfunc(log_fact, 1, 1)(x) + b*x + c

File "./fit2.py", line 30, in logfactfunc
    return a*np.frompyfunc(log_fact, 1, 1)(x) + b*x + c
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.float64
```

Any ideas on how I can get my log_fact() function to be used within the curve_fit() function??

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` really is large (say larger than about 10 or so) then a **much** better approach is to using *Stirling's approximation*.  This will be much more efficient.  It will also be easy to vectorize.

For the approach you are taking your `log_fact(n)` function can be written much more efficiently and compactly as

```
def log_fact(n) :
    return np.sum(np.log(np.arange(1,n+1)))
```

This does not help with your problem though.  We could vectorize this as @Isaac shows or just use `np.vectorize()` which is a convenience wrapper that does basically the same thing.  Note that it does **not** offer speed advantages, you are still using Python loops which are slow.

That being said, use Stirling's approximation!

Answer (score 6):

Your `log_fact` function is closely related to the `gammaln` function, which is defined as a ufunc in `scipy.special`. Specifically, `log_fact(n) == scipy.special.gammaln(n+1)`. For even modest values of `n`, this is significantly faster:

```
In [15]: %timeit log_fact(19)
10000 loops, best of 3: 24.4 us per loop
In [16]: %timeit scipy.special.gammaln(20)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.13 us per loop
```

Also, the running time of `gammaln` is independent of `n`, unlike `log_fact`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `log_fact` function is being called with arrays as input parameters, which is what's throwing off your method. A possible way of vectorizing your code would be the following:

```
def log_fact(n):
    n = np.asarray(n)
    m = np.max(n)
    return np.take(np.cumsum(np.log(np.arange(1, m+1))), n-1)
```

Taking it for a test ride:

```
>>> log_fact(3)
1.791759469228055
>>> log_fact([10, 15, 23])
array([ 15.10441257,  27.89927138,  51.60667557])
>>> log_fact([[10, 15, 23], [14, 15, 8]])
array([[ 15.10441257,  27.89927138,  51.60667557],
       [ 25.19122118,  27.89927138,  10.6046029 ]])
```

The only caveat with this approach is that it stores an array as long as the largest value you call it with. If your `n` gets into the billions, you'll probably break it. Other than that, it actually avoids repeated calculations if you call it with many values.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell creating a `ufunc` is fairly involved, and my require writing your function in c. See [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/c-info.ufunc-tutorial.html) for the documentation on creating ufuncs.

You might instead consider just writing a version of your function that takes and returns `ndarray`s. For instance:

```
def logfact_arr(a):
  return np.array([log_fact(x) for x in a.flat]).reshape(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers show efficient ways to solve your problem. But the precise answer to your question, i.e., how to vectorize `log_fact` function is to use `np.vectorize`:

```
vlog_fact=np.vectorize(log_fact)
def vlogfactfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a*vlog_fact(x) + b*x + c
```

With that, you can call `curve_fit(vlogfactfunc, np.array([1,2,3]), np.array([ -1. , 4.465 , 11.958]))`

As you suggested, you could also use `np.frompyfunc` but as you can read in its documentation, that always returns python objects, as then `curve_fit` complains:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
```

A workaround is to covert the returned array to an array of floats:

```
ulog_fact = np.frompyfunc(log_fact, 1,1) 
def ulogfactfunc(x, a, b, c):
    return a*ulog_fact(x).astype(np.float) + b*x + c
```

So you can also call `curve_fit` with `ulogfactfunc`
Hope this helps!